# Determining an equivalence class

Tags: modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

Let $S = \mathbb{Z}$ and $a ∼ b ⇐⇒ 3|(a + 2b)$.

1. Show that $∼$ is an equivalence relation.
2. Determine all equivalence classes for $∼$.

Part $1$ was pretty simple to prove, however I can't figure out how to proceed with part $2$. I'm thinking of either doing classes by the coefficient $m$ such that $3m = a+2b$ (ex: $cl(1) = (1,1) , (-1,2), (-3,3)... $  for $(a,b)$ ), by the sum of $a+2b$ (ex: $cl(0) = (-2,1)$ because $-2+2(1) = 0$ ), or just a single class where this relation exists (ex: all the values of $(a,b)$ where $3|(a + 2b)$. The last one wouldn't partition the set $S$ obviously, because it would only take the values divisible by $3$.

As a follow up thought, all $3$ of my methods seem incorrect to me, as the set $S$ is only $\mathbb{Z}$, which implies that we are only looking for single integer values in each class, not the $(a,b)$ coordinates that I put in my classes. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Take $a=1$ for example, and start going through the positive integers (just for example) and seeing which ones are equivalent to $1$. Can you spot a pattern?

Comment: You might also find it useful to show that if $a\sim b$, then $a\sim b+3$.

Comment: If $a=1$, in order to satisfy the relation, $b=1,4,7,10,...$ ? And if $a=2, b= 2,5,8,...$ So would I have $3$ classes: $cl(0) , cl(1), cl(2)$?

Comment: More dupes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1005887/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1040670/242).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$a\sim b\iff a\equiv b\pmod 3$$

In other words $3|a+2b$ iff $3|a-b$

Comment: Gotcha. So would the classes be $cl(0), cl(1), cl(2)$ in terms of what $a$ is? Because we can say that for $cl(0) = 0,3,6...$, $0 \equiv 3 \equiv (6 $ mod $ 3) $?

Comment: Precisely $cl(0)=\bar{0}$, $cl(1)=\bar{1}$, $cl(2)=\bar{2}\mod 3$

Comment: Thank you!!! That helped alot